# imported Segoe UI semlight font won't load on css

Tags: html, css, fonts

Segoe UI semlight is a font designed for Windows 7, I really like this font and I'm building a web-application using it, I want clients using windows XP and other operation systems to be able to view it as well, so I saved the font on my web files folder and imported it to the CSS code, however it simply won't load, This isn't a directory error or incorrect importing of the font, I've tested other fonts and it worked fine, **It doesn't work with this font specifically** I would be glad if any of you have a clue why it won't load with this font specific......

Comment: Windows XP means older IE. Older IE means EOT format, and an EOT file could not be displayed if the license information inside is missing

Comment: The question lacks any relevant code and diagnostic information (which should be found in the browser’s console). Moreover, this may be caused by an unauthorized use of a proprietary font as a web font.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer from Microsoft, I hope it help you:

> *We made Segoe UI Semilight so that a light weight font could be used at smaller sizes than Segoe UI Light. Segoe UI Light really doesn't work below 20pt (@96ppi), wheras Segoe UI Semilight survives down to about 11pt. There's always a chance the font may end up on Windows 7 as part of a broadly deployed update, but we've not made any commitment to that effect. For now we'd recommend specifying Segoe UI Regular at sizes below 20pt.*

Try changing the font-size and maybe will work